# How to edit value in C++Builder Registry?

Tags: registry, c++builder, c++builder-xe2

I use C++Builder XE2 and want to use the Console Application wizard, but it is broken.  I have read [Create Win32 application in C++Builder XE5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29283438/), and see I need to set the following value in the Registry:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\<version>\Repository\New Console Application

(REG_SZ) "ConsoleApp" = "True" or "False"
```

But I don't know where to enter that.

Comment: This question makes no sense, please try to rephrase.  You can edit the registry using the "regedit" program that comes with Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run Windows' built-in Registry Editor, `regedit.exe` (Start > Run > type `regedit` > press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, answer Yes if prompted).

In the left-hand pane, navigate down to the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\9.0\Repository\New Console Application` key.

In the right-hand pane, if `ConsoleApp` does not already exist, right-click in a blank area (or use the "Edit" menu in the upper toolbar), choose "New > String value", and enter `ConsoleApp`.

[image]

[image]

Now double-click on `ConsoleApp` and type `True` or `False` as needed.

[image]

[image]

The change will take effect the next time the Console Application wizard is opened.

Comment: Thank you so much you are a kind teaching! you solve my problem!